# Wi-Fi password from passphrase and hex

Tags: wireless-networking, passwords, hex-editor

On my Wi-Fi box, I have set a passphrase and also know the hex code. However, my iPhone needs a password.

Can I figure out the password from this information?

How else can I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

The passphrase *is* the password. When [done right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passphrase), it is a long password though.

(However, as you also have a Hex version, it seems you're not using WPA or WPA2? WEP is not very secure, so change to WPA2 if possible, or WPA as your second choice! Also note that WEP has some problems with non-standard password lengths. [Choose](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1344) 5 characters for a 40 bit WEP, or 13 characters for 128 bit. Still, use WPA2 when possible!)

Answer (score 2):

Go to http://www.corecoding.com/utilities/wep2hex.php and type in your passphrase - it should be converted to hex for you.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone has several choices for connecting to Wi-Fi (well, the iPod does, so I'm assuming that it's the same for the iPhone). Are you selecting the correct one? If you've set your Wi-Fi to [WPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access) access you'll need to select that option on the iPhone and that should ask you for the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

As @arjan said this is an issue stemming from using WEP as opposed to WPA or WPA2 encryption both of which the iPhone supports.  I would advise switching away from WEP as soon as possible as it is [trivial](http://www.shawnhogan.com/2006/08/how-to-crack-128-bit-wireless-networks.html) [to break](http://www.wikihow.com/Break-WEP-Encryption) [WEP encryption](http://www.google.com/search?q=crack+wep+encryption).  Also WPA does not mess about with hex-keys.  Your password is you password, no extra info is required.